# xpath pattern for all specific forms in html page

Tags: python, html, forms, selenium, xpath

I have to locate all "login-form"-like forms in the html page. The requirement for such for is that it contains text input field, password field and button (submit or just a button).

There shouldn't be any element names mentioned, because it should work through different language mutations.

And I need to find all forms in the page, which fits these requirements. I guess it could be done using xpath, but I can't figure out any working pattern.

By the way, I'm using webdriver with python.

Comment: What are the patterns that you have tries so far? Why did they not work? Could you include your attempts and possible error messages into your question? Also we would need a stripped down! input HTML page to work with. Otherwise it's just guessing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need an XPath expression to match every `form` element (`//form`) which has among its descendants an `input` element of `type=password` (`[.//input[@type='password']]`), a standard `input` field (`[.//input[not(@type) or @type='' or @type='text']]`) and a submit button (`[.//input[@type='submit'] or .//button[not(@type) or @type='' or @type='submit']]`).

All together becomes

```
//form[.//input[@type='password']][.//input[not(@type) or @type='' or @type='text']][.//input[@type='submit'] or .//button[not(@type) or @type='' or @type='submit']]
```

It may not match every form, since for the submit button and the text input field it's difficult to make an always working rule. The problem when dealing with such elements is that they have many `type` values, and if it is provided an invalid *type* they defaults to the `text` or `submit` state. For example a input element my have the `type` attribute set to `nonvalidtype`, and it will still be a standard text input.

Also, the `type` attribute is case insensitive, and the correct XPath expression that considers this is more complicated, it also needs XPath 2.0:

```
//form[.//input[lower-case(@type)='password']][.//input[not(@type) or @type='' or lower-case(@type)='text']][.//input[lower-case(@type)='submit'] or .//button[not(@type) or @type='' or lower-case(@type)='submit']]
```

Comment: Thank you, this might be what I'm looking for. I avare of the fact that probably no approach will cover 100% cases I need.